# Div with two divs inside the same size (img inside)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have a div with an image be on the same line as another div that allows other divs to be be stacked on top of each other in the right side?

Here is an image I created with what I am trying to achieve. Thank you:
http://postimg.org/image/82fg886hb/

```
<div class="media">
      <div style="display:inline">
        <img src="images/sample.png" width="92px" height="135px" >
      <div>
      <div style="display:inline;" > Points: 1422</div>
      <div style="display:inline;"> Level: 17</div>
      <div style="display:inline;">
        <img src="images/experienceBar.png" >
      </div>
    </div><!-- End div .media -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add width and float it left

e.g

```
<style>
    .cls_my{
        float:left;
        width:300px;
    }
</style>
<div style="display:inline;" class ='cls_my' > Points: 1422</div>
      <div style="display:inline;" class='cls_my'> Level: 17</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use float to change a elements flow. Here is an example:

```css
.media .container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.media .container img,
.media .container .side {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="media">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x200" width="92px" height="135px" />
        <div class="side">
            <div>Points: 1422</div>
            <div>Level: 17</div>
            <div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/100x40" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```